# Optimize Mysql Query in a attribute value database

Tags: mysql, optimization, performance

I've got a database but I forsee a problem with the speed.
Because all my data is saved seperately

```
Product table:
id int auto_inc PRI
name var_char(64)

attribute_table:
attr_id int auto_inc PRI
name var_char(64)

attribute_value:
attr_id int
product_id
value
```

but when I do a advanced search I get enorm querys like

```
select * from product_table  as pt
cross join attribute_value as av ON av.product_id = pt.id AND av.value LIKE "test"
cross join attribute_table as at ON at.attr_id = av.attr_id AND at.name = "test"
cross join attribute_value as av ON av.product_id = pt.id AND av.value LIKE "test2"
cross join attribute_table as at ON at.attr_id = av.attr_id AND at.name = "test2"
cross join attribute_value as av ON av.product_id = pt.id AND av.value LIKE "test3"
cross join attribute_table as at ON at.attr_id = av.attr_id AND at.name = "test3"
```

but I guess this isnt realy fast. but is there a way to optimse? or some tricks I can use to search faster like a kind of cashing?

Comment: What exactly is your query supposed to be doing? You probably want to be using LEFT JOIN, and probably want to add some indexes, but until I can figure what you are trying to select I can't really help you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want something more like this:

```
select * from product_table as pt JOIN attribute_value as av 
    ON av.product_id = pt.id
WHERE (av.value LIKE "test") 
    OR (at.name = "test") 
    OR (av.value LIKE "test2") 
    OR (at.name = "test2") ....
```

That gets you a single join, with a select from the result.  I think that's closer to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd rewrite it (I don't understand why you join the same tables multiple times  ):

```
select * from product_table  as pt
INNER join attribute_value as av ON (av.product_id = pt.id AND av.value LIKE "test%")
INNER join attribute_table as at ON (at.attr_id = av.attr_id AND at.name LIKE "test%")
```

Next,  run `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to check execution plain. It shows which indexes are currently used for the query.
  Then, make sure you have indexes on columns that are used for joining tables - you should have indexes(at least) on attribute_value.product_id, attribute_table.attr_id .
Finally, select only what you need, not `*`.